# XSD not valid: Cannot resolve the name xxx to a(n) 'element declaration' component

Tags: xml, xaml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the below XSD that I generated from a profile that I serialize using XAML 2009. However when my I put the schema in [Online Validator](http://xsdvalidation.utilities-online.info/) I get src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'scg:List' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. error.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:csu="clr-namespace:ConfigurationUtilityFunctions.Section.User;assembly=ConfigurationUtilityFunctions" xmlns:csw="clr-namespace:ConfigurationUtilityFunctions.Section.WebConfig;assembly=ConfigurationUtilityFunctions" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="clr-namespace:ConfigurationUtilityFunctions;assembly=ConfigurationUtilityFunctions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import namespace="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" />
  <xs:element name="ConfigProfile">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ConfigProfile.ConfigSections">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="scg:List" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="ProfileId" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="InstanceName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="ProfileDesc" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="ProfileName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="ProfileType" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="IISSection">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="AnonymousUser" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="ApplicationPoolName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="Port" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="VirtualDirectoryAlias" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="WebsiteName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="WebsiteRoot" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML namespace `scg` is actually referring to:

```
clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib
```

I doubt whether your schema validator has access to the `mscorlib` assembly.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I have to wait a few more minutes before it will allow me to accept it though.

Comment: @twreid No problem. I do wonder why you have a schema referring to the  `Generic.List` object.

Comment: I generate that schema from a profile that my application creates. The profile gets serialized with a XAML writer as XML. Then when I deserialize it I have my profile object ready to go.

Comment: I use the .Net XmlSchemaInference and XmlSchemaSet classes to generate and write out the schemas and the above is what I got from doing that.